# How can i compare arrays in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I want to compare data present in an array with the data retrieved from a class using .each in cypress?

Using below code i have tried to iterate over the FileType array using below code.

```js
const Filetype = ['Access', 'Excel', 'Text/CSV','PDF','JSON','dsdsd'];
const te = cy.wrap($bodyFind).find('.data-sourcename').should('have.length',6).each(($li) => { cy.log($li.text()); });

te.each(($text)=> {
cy.log("Te" + $text); 
//prints ['Access','Excel','Text/CSV','PDF','JSON','XML'];
});

// Converted FileType Array to Cypress object using cy.wrap command.
const cywrap = cy.wrap(Filetype);
      te.each((e1)=>cywrap.each((e2)=> {
      if(e1 == e2) {
         expect(e1).equals(e2);
       }
     }));
```

But the value of e1 and e2 is same.
expect should fail with 'dsdsd' is equals 'XML'
whereas it passes with 'dsdsd' is equals 'dsdsd'

Answer (score 15):

You could use `map` here.

```js
const filetypes = ['Access', 'Excel', 'Text/CSV','PDF','JSON','dsdsd'];
cy.get('.data-sourcename').should(($els) => {
  // map jquery elements to array of their innerText
  const elsText = $els.toArray().map(el => el.innerText)
  expect(elsText).to.deep.eq(filetypes)
})
```

Comment: const filetypes = ['Access', 'Excel', 'Text/CSV','PDF','JSON','dsdsd'];
cy.wrap($bodyFind).find('.data-source-name').should('have.length',6).each(($els) => {   
  const elsText = $els.toArray().map(el => el.innerText);
  const ft = filetypes.map(ft=>ft);     }); //output of elsText is coming as '[Access]' '[Excel]' .... enable to check it with ft.

Comment: You may need to tweak the code, you can click on the assertion in the correct Cypress command log with devtools console open to inspect the values

Comment: i needed to use the following for this approach to work because (as of March 2021), Cypress was using a JQuery map (i, el) instead of (el, i): `const elsText = $els.map((i,el) => el.innerText)).toArray()`  Also needed to call `toArray()` after extracting inner text

Answer (score 3):

I hope by now you must have found out the solution for this. But still, there was no selected answers yet, thought I would add one.

```
const Filetype = ['Access', 'Excel', 'Text/CSV','PDF','JSON','dsdsd'];

cy
   .get('whatever element')
   .each(($span, i) => {
        expect($span.text()).to.equal(Filetype[i]);
   });
```

`$span` would go through each element and `.text()`will get the text value of that element.