# Cypress assert values in array

Tags: arrays, cypress, cypress-intercept

I am trying to assert the value's in an array.
At this moment I made it to assert just the length:

```js
cy.get('@UrlAndAppendices')
  .its('request.body.correctionInstructionAppendices')
  .should('have.length', 2)
```

What is the best way to compare this?
I can make an deep equal with a fixture. But I dont think that this would be the cleanest solution for assertin just 2 value's in a array.

[image: Result in cypress]

Comment: Does this answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58110351/how-can-i-compare-arrays-in-cypress

Answer (score 2):

For something as simple as two items, best readability (more concise code) is to assert inline.

Length of 2 is implied in the `deep.eq` check (i.e 1 item would fail, and 3 items would fail).

```js
cy.get('@UrlAndAppendices')
  .its('request.body.correctionInstructionAppendices')
  .should('deep.eq', ['abc', '123'])
```

or this way

```js
cy.get('@UrlAndAppendices')
  .its('request.body.correctionInstructionAppendices')
  .should('include', 'abc')                     
  .and('include', '123')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values will not change in the array then you can create a variable to check against.

```js
const arrValues = [2, 3]
cy.get('@UrlAndAppendices')
  .its('request.body.correctionInstructionAppendices')
  .should('have.length', 2)
  .and('deep.equal', arrValues)
```

Here is an example with using a [fixture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73950110/17917809) instead.